# i am facing php validation issues on my login page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am facing some issues when i use this code...when i put wrong password or empty it works but it removes css file and also mouse scroll button does  not work, and also remove header from my login page.this is my website link. Kindly someone help me please, http://www.tril.la/dev2/login/

```
    $page_id = "";
    $product_pages_args = array(
        'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
        'meta_value' => 'login.php'
    );

    $product_pages = get_pages( $product_pages_args );
    foreach ( $product_pages as $product_page ) {
        $page_id.= $product_page->ID;
    }

    function goto_login_page() {

    global $page_id;
    $login_page = home_url( '/?page_id='. $page_id. '/' );
    $page = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        if( $page == "wp-login.php" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
            wp_redirect($login_page);
            exit;
        }
    }
    add_action('init','goto_login_page');

    function login_failed() {
        global $page_id;
        $login_page = home_url( '/?page_id='. $page_id. '/' );
        wp_redirect( $login_page . '&login=failed' );
        exit;
    }
    add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'login_failed' );

    function blank_username_password( $user, $username, $password ) {
        global $page_id;
        $login_page = home_url( '/?page_id='. $page_id. '/' );
        if( $username == "" || $password == "" ) {
            wp_redirect( $login_page . "&login=blank" );
        exit;
        }
    }
    add_filter( 'authenticate', 'blank_username_password', 1, 3);

    //echo $login_page = $page_path ;

    function logout_page() {
        global $page_id;
        $login_page = home_url( '/?page_id='. $page_id. '/' );
        wp_redirect( $login_page . "&login=false" );
        exit;
    }
    add_action('wp_logout', 'logout_page');

    $page_showing = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    if (strpos($page_showing, 'failed') !== false) {
        echo '<p class="error-msg"><strong>ERROR:</strong> Invalid username and/or password.</p>';
    }
    elseif (strpos($page_showing, 'blank') !== false ) {
        echo '<p class="error-msg"><strong>ERROR:</strong> Username and/or Password is empty.</p>';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the error message is displayed before the rest of your output. Make sure you display the error message after the header.

Comment: i put my code at different places but every time i faced that error..would you like to tell me the exact place of error mesaage thanks

Comment: Please put the whole php script here.